# Can MySQL return the portion of the string matching a regular expression?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I would like to use the group capture in a regular expression to parse a string. Can this be done with MySQL?

For example,

```
SELECT my_wishful_function('->hello world<-', '/->(.*)<-/')
```

and have it return:

```
hello world
```

Comment: Your wishful function is `regexp_substr()`:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 5.7, if the boundaries `->` and `<-` only occur once in the string, you can use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) twice to extract the portion between the boundaries:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('I said ->hello world<- today', '->', -1), '<-', 1)
```

Output

```
hello world
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL regex engine does not support backreferences, unlike other RDBMS such as Oracle or Postgres.

You can use `regexp_replace()` instead. That is, remove the unwanted parts instead of capturing the wanted part:

```
select regexp_replace('->hello world<-', '(^->)|(<-$)', '')
```

Regexp explanation: `^->` is the unwanted part at the beginning of the string, and `<-$` is the unwanted part at the end of the string. We surround the parts with parentheses to define groups, and separate them with `|`, which means *or*.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d8013876d6643419eb145b3e751f4dc5)**:

```
select regexp_replace('->hello world<-', '(^->)|(<-$)', '') new_col
```

```
| new_col     |
| :---------- |
| hello world |
```

Comment: Just to extend support for REGEXP was introduced with MySQL 8. [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql/49925597#49925597)

Comment: Any solution for MySQL 5.7? 

Answer (score 2):

An elegant solution is to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()` and positive lookahead/behind assertions :

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('->hello world<-', '(?<=->).*(?=<-)');
-- hello world
```

`(?<=...)` is a positive lookbehind assertion : we check matching pattern is preceded by `...`

`(?=...)` is a positive lookahead assertion : we check matching pattern is followed by `...`

These assertions are not capturing, so we don't need to delete delimiters `->` and `<-`

It's compatible with MySQL 8